# Missing characters - swedish ÅÖÄ - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, character-encoding, asp-classic

When retrieving customer data from a myslq-server after entering some key-data - the swedish åöä are missing - or rather look like a questionmark in a black box. I cannot really get it! I have using charset-utf8 in both the asp-file, the html-file and in the script tag that includes the js file.

I have been studying the incoming json-protocol with wireshark and I can see that theres a questionmark already there - that is, the problem is coming from the server-side.

the html-file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
</head>


<body>
...
```

the asp-file (snippet)

```
<%response.Charset="UTF-8"%> 


<%
 Response.ContentType = "application/json"
...


response.write("{""customerdata"":[{""fname"": """ & fetched_fName & """,""lname"": """ & fetched_lName & """,""street"": """ & fetched_address & """,""zipcode"": """ & fetched_zipcode & """, ""email"": """ & fetched_email & """,""mobile"": """ & fetched_mobile & """}]}")

....
```

The purpose with the asp-file is to fetch sql-data and them format those to json. Could the problem arise here? Just a guess!

Would be very glad if this could be solved!

Comment: Isnt the problem from the database access already? Assuming it is stored in the database correctly, have you checked which encoding you use to get the data out og the server?

Comment: @MattiasÅslund - Have not yet but forget to mention - when not using json and ajax, the problem is not there. So I guess its json?

Comment: Json is just a way to format a steing. It is encoding agnostic. And ajax has no inherent problem with encodings. Start by verifying what string/encoding you have on the server..

Comment: Try adding `response.codepage = 65001`. This is worth a read if you haven't seen it - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InternationalizationAndClassicASP.aspx

Comment: @John - THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! That solved the problem!!!!! :-)

Comment: There are plenty of answers on encoding issues in Classic ASP on [so], seems to come up a few times a week...